# Как удалить дубликаты из потокобезопасной очереди?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Как удалить дубликаты из потокобезопасной очереди (например ConcurrentQueue) с максимальной производительностью?

Comment: Опишите задачу в целом. Как данные с дубликатами попадают в эту очередь? Может, дубликаты можно предварительно удалить, перед помещением данных в очередь? "Свободна" ли очередь в данный момент или с ней работают другие потоки?

Comment: На самом деле, непонятно, как сделать это **корректно** хоть с какой производительностью. Что если во время энумерации будут добавляться и исчезать элементы?

Answer (score 3):

Есть [старая оценка для C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041620/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-erase-duplicates-and-sort-a-vector), что преобразование в set было самым быстрым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в при чем тут плюсы?

Comment: @Alexis есть мнение, что это фундаментальная задача, которая мало зависит от языка.